# Editing an existing contact in modal (bootstrap-ui angular)

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-ui-bootstrap

I have built a addressBook holder, which should allow a user:

```
1. create an address, by entering details in modal pop up; 
2.delete an address and 
3.edit an address that already exists by entering details in modal pop up.
```

Essentially a simple CRUD app, with all data stored by using `localStorage`. It looks like I need something [like the solution here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11818235/edit-object-via-modal-in-angularjs-use-a-temporary-object), but I am not hundred percent sure how I would do this.

I have implemented both the creation and deleting of an address, but am having difficulties implementing the editing of an address that already exists.

With the code I have below when I click the edit contact button, it opens the modal, but when I enter the details into the form it creates a new address as opposed to editing the one I clicked on.

This is happening as I am not distinguishing between the two. Any guidance on how to change the code to allow me edit an address would be brilliant. I have spent the last few hours trying to figure this out but am completely stuck. Please see the code below. (Apologies for the amount of code, but I think it is necessary to solve this)

Here is the **javascript**

**Angular factory**

```
app.factory('addressFactory', function(){
    var addressFactory = {};
    addressFactory.addressBook = [];

    addressFactory.countries = [
        {name: "United Kingdom"},
        {name: "United States of America"}
    ];

    addressFactory.saveAddress = function(name, country){
        addressFactory.addressBook.push({
            name: name, 
            country: country
        });
        localStorage.setItem('addressBook', JSON.stringify(addressFactory.addressBook));
    };

    addressFactory.deleteAddress = function(index) {
        addressFactory.addressBook.splice(index, 1); 
        localStorage.setItem('addressBook', JSON.stringify(addressFactory.addressBook)); 
    }

    return addressFactory;
})
```

**Angular controllers**

**first controller(testCtrl)**

```
app.controller('testCtrl', function ($routeParams, $uibModal, addressFactory) {

var testCtrl = this;
this.addressBook = addressFactory.addressBook;

this.init = function() {
    addressFactory.init();
    this.addressBook = addressFactory.addressBook;
}

this.deleteAddress = function(index){
    addressFactory.deleteAddress(index);
};

this.open = function () {
    testCtrl.modalInstance = $uibModal.open({
      templateUrl: 'app/views/partials/form.html',
      controller: 'ModalCtrl',
      controllerAs:'ctrl',
    });
}

this.init();

})
```

**second controller(ModalCtrl)**

```
.controller('ModalCtrl', function ($uibModalInstance,addressFactory) {

    this.addressBook = addressFactory.addressBook;
    this.countries = addressFactory.countries;

    this.saveAddress = function( name, country) {
        addressFactory.saveAddress( name,country);
        $uibModalInstance.dismiss('cancel');
    }

    this.cancelAddress = function () {
        $uibModalInstance.dismiss('cancel');
    };

})
```

**index.html**

```
  <!-- used to open a modal to create a new address -->
  <a ng-click="ctrl.open()">Enter new address</a>


   <div ng-repeat="contact in ctrl.addressBook track by $index"> 
        <p class="contactName">{{contact.name}}</p>
        <p class="contactCountry">{{contact.country}}</p>

        <!-- used open a modal to edit a new address -->
        <button ng-click="ctrl.open()">Edit Contact</button>
        <button ng-click="ctrl.deleteAddress($index)">Delete Contact</button>
   </div>
```

**form.html**

```
<form>
    <input ng-model="ctrl.name" type="text">
    <select ng-model="ctrl.country" ng-options="country.name for country in ctrl.countries">
        <option value="">--Choose a country--</option>
    </select>
        <button ng-click="ctrl.cancelAddress()">Cancel</button>
        <button ng-click="ctrl.saveAddress(ctrl.name, ctrl.country.name)">Save</button>
</form>
```

Comment: Well, to make your life easy, I guess you could just add the new entry and delete the old one. So now all you need to do is delete the old entry after adding the updated one

Comment: @Adjit I think i need to be able to edit, like a CRUD application

Comment: Can you pass `$index` to `ctrl.saveAddress(ctrl.name, ctrl.country.name, $index)` and then if the `$index` is valid update the corresponding entry?

Comment: @Adjit how would that look like in the factory/controller?

Comment: Just like you're passing another parameter to the function. so like `function( name, country, index)` then if a valid index has been passed you can just call `addressFractory.addressBook[index].name = name` to change the name property. Then just change the statement to alter other properties.

Comment: @Adjit the issue there is for a new contact, there will not be any `index` as it is not in `ng-repeat`

Comment: Ahh right, it's a modal. Wasn't sure if the form existed inside the repeat. Well, in that case take a look here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18576454/pass-parameter-to-modal

Comment: @Adjit Those answers don't really appear to help. Would you be able to provide an answer here as to how to implement this?

Comment: Honestly, not too sure what would do it. I know some Angular, but this is beyond me, so was offering some suggestions of things I would try.

Comment: @Adjit i know, i had used `resolve` and was able to access the data, but couldn't update the current item

Comment: How are you trying to update the item? you need to access the addressBook array and change the properties at a certain index. ie - `addressFactory.addressBook[index].name = name`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can pass the index of the edited item to the modal with `testCtrl.modalInstance.idx = index`:

```
app.controller('testCtrl', function ($routeParams, $uibModal, addressFactory) {
  this.open = function (index) {
    testCtrl.modalInstance = $uibModal.open({
      templateUrl: 'form-modal.html',
      controller: 'ModalCtrl',
      controllerAs:'ctrl',
    });
    testCtrl.modalInstance.idx = index;
  }
  ...
```

[Here is a codepen](http://codepen.io/C14L/pen/JXLqgv) that can edit and save items, based on if they have or don't have an index.

Comment: Good example. I had a similar issue and was able to resolve it using the codepen.